# Apache Flink on Windows

Tags: windows, apache-flink

First, I am a complete newbie with Flink. I have installed Apache Flink on Windows.
I start Flink with start-cluster.bat. It prints out

> Starting a local cluster with one JobManager process and one
>   TaskManager process. You can terminate the processes via CTRL-C in the
>   spawned shell windows. Web interface by default on
>   http://localhost:8081/.

Anyway, when I submit the job, I have a bunch of messages:

> DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient - Received response
>   {"status":{"id":"IN_PROGRESS"}}.

In the log in the web UI at http://localhost:8081/, I see:

> 2019-02-15 16:04:23.571 [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] WARN 
>   akka.remote.ReliableDeliverySupervisor
>   flink-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6 - Association with
>   remote system [akka.tcp://flink@127.0.0.1:56404] has failed, address
>   is now gated for [50] ms. Reason: [Disassociated]

If I go to the Task Manager tab, it is empty.

I tried to find if any port needed by flink was in use but it does not seem to be the case.

Any idea to solve this?

Comment: You'll have a better experience on windows if you use the bash shell and the bash scripts that come with flink.

Answer (score 0):

So I was running Flink locally using Intelij 
Using ArchType that gives you ready to go examples

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/projectsetup/java_api_quickstart.html

You not necessary have to install it unless you are using Flink as a service on cluster.
Code editor will compile it just fine for spot instance of Flink for one code run.

Comment: OK, but my goal here is to run on a standalone cluster, not in the IDE.

Comment: Yeah only one thing I saw on it was https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/tutorials/flink_on_windows.html. But I ended up setting up YARN/HDFS on Centos7  amd put flink on top